# mecabの分かち書きが遅すぎて終わらない

Tags: python, 自然言語処理

tsvファイルから文書を呼び出し、MeCabを用いて特定の品詞を基本形で分かち書きするコードを動かしているのですが重すぎて５時間以上経った今でも処理が終わりません。
PCのスペック自体そこまでいいわけではないのですが、ほかのコードを動かしているときにはこのようなことはなかったので、何かコードに問題があるのではないかと思い、質問させていただきます。

```
with open("jurycomment2.tsv",mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # reports.tsvには一行に口コミID,口コミがtab区切りで保存されている
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for report_id, report in reader:
        words = []
        node = mt.parseToNode(report)
        while node:
                if node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"名詞":
                        words.append(node.surface)
                elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"形容詞":
                        words.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
                elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":
                        words.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
                        node = node.next
        stopword = []
        words2 = [token for token in words if token not in stopword]
        # wordsが文章の単語のリスト,tagsには文章IDを指定
        reports.append(TaggedDocument(words=words2, tags=[report_id]))
```

tsvファイルは500kbほどですのでこのファイルは原因ではないと思われます。

Comment: `node = node.next` のインデントの高さが `elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":`文の内部になってしまっているので、ほぼ無限ループに近い形になってしまっているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます、ご指摘の通りインテンドに問題がありました。

Answer (score 1):

node = node.next のインデントの高さが elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":文の内部になってしまっているので、ほぼ無限ループに近い形になってしまっているのではないでしょうか。